# Syntax error when adding to a variable in a while true loop

Tags: python

So I'm new to python, and I was just messing around with some code I made and it kept giving me a syntax error when I try to run it. I couldn't find anything on it so I assume its very simple but I can't figure it out. help pls.

```
factor = 1;
ness = "yes";
while True: {
    factor += 1
    print (ness*factor)
}
```

Comment: It will generally tell you what the syntax errors are as well.

Comment: Drop the curly braces around `while` loop. Python uses indentation to figure out what is in which block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't use `{}` for control constructs. Just remove the braces and the semicolons, and you'll be fine.

Comment: hmm, an infinite while loop is fine?

Comment: It doesn't use semicolons either, and depending on the version of Python, there should also be no parentheses after the `print` statement.

Comment: Semicolons are actually legal, but generally are against PEP8

Answer (score 0):

There is  no semicolon in python statements and no braces in the loops
your code doesn't check any condition it will lead to a indefinite loop. just change the code

```
factor = 1
ness = "yes"
while factor<=10: 
    factor += 1
    print (ness*factor)
```

and the output is

```
yesyes
yesyesyes
yesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes
```